# PHP: How can I tweak PHPUnit to use a different PHP interpreter?

Tags: php, configuration, xampp, phpunit

My system has two PHP interpreters. One came bundled with the OS and the other I installed via the XAMPP package. All of my PHP extensions are applied to the XAMPP installation but PHPUnit seems to only run the version of PHP that came with my machine.

Does anybody know of a way I can configure or rebuild PHPUnit so that it uses my XAMPP PHP interpreter exclusively?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find the folder you installed PHPUnit in. There should be a file called phpunit.bat. It should have a line that reads something like

```
set PHPBIN="C:\php\php.exe"
%PHPBIN% "C:\php\phpunit" %*
```

Change it to read

```
set PHPBIN="C:\xampp\php\php.exe"
%PHPBIN% "C:\xampp\php\phpunit" %*
```

Or whatever the path to your PHP executable is

Answer (score 10):

For Mac/Linux, the first line of the phpunit script with starts with

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

change that to

```
#!/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php
```

or whatever other php interpret you want to use.

Comment: And in case you are not sure where your other PHP is running from, just try `php -i` from terminal and look for `$_SERVER['_'] `.

Answer (score 2):

Since modifying phpunit file did not work for me because of phar signature errors, I was running phpunit with different php version by calling interpreter explicitly  (on Linux):

```
php7.1 /usr/local/bin/phpunit
php5.6 /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

Following the example with XAMPP, full path to php interpreter could be provided:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

Answer (score 1):

In agreement with Thomas' statement, additionally there's a line further below

```
if (strpos('/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php', '@php_bin') === 0) {
    set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__) . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
}
```

That I've been told you're also supposed to change to reflect the PHP you're interested in using
(I've set mine to MAMP obviously)

I've switched back and forth from 5.2 and 5.3 a lot recently  :)

Answer (score 0):

This applies to phpunit installed using Homebrew on Mac OS 10.9. I’ve editing the file located at /usr/local/Cellar/phpunit/4.2.6/bin as seen below. CAVEAT: I don’t know how Homebrew will handle this on a PhpUnit update, but for now it’s working to be able to select the php version that PhpUnit is using for it's testing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

php=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/bin/php
#php=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/php

/usr/bin/env $php -d allow_url_fopen=On -d detect_unicode=Off /usr/local/Cellar/phpunit/4.2.6/libexec/phpunit-4.2.6.phar $*
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, this may be achieved using a similar approach to the ones mentioned in other replies.

In your `/path/to/composer/phpunit` directory, open the `phpunit` file in an editor. The first line should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Simply [download your desired version of PHP for Windows](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/), place the contents of the ZIP file somewhere to your liking, and reference the fully quantified path to the `php.exe` file, instead of just `php`. Like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /c/misc/php-5.5.9-nts-Win32-VC11-x86/php.exe
```

In my case, I put it in `/c/misc/php-5.5.9-nts-Win32-VC11-x86/`, which corresponds to `C:\misc\php-5.5.9-nts-Win32-VC11-x86\` using Windows path syntax.

Remember to verify that the correct `php.ini` file is being used (`php --ini` or in a script file `php_ini_loaded_file()`).